# Comparing two strings with wildcard conditions

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a VBA macro that compares string values, and have hit a wall at a point.

Here is some context on what I'm trying to accomplish:
Compare two strings, If String 2 is CONTAINED anywhere in String 1, I return a match. For the most part, I've used the builtin "instr" function in instances where the String 2 is contained in String 1 without any wildcards involved.

The trouble I'm having is that I must treat spaces or " " in String 2 as a wildcard.
Ex:

String 1 = Red Green Blue

String 2 = Red Blue

This should still return a valid match, since the " " in String 2 is being treated as a wildcard, and any number of characters can be between "Red" and "Blue"

What I did was use the "split" function with " " as a delimiter to split String 2 in instances where a space(" ") is involved, and run an instr function on the resulting array to check if each element of the array is contained in  String 1. In the example above:

String 2 would be split into a String array(let's call with splitString) with the following elements:
splitString = (Red, Blue)

Using the logic above:

splitString(0) is contained in String 1

splitString(1) is contained in String 1

Therefore, String 2 is contained in String 1, and a match is returned. The match condition I am using is utilizing the UBounds value of splitString (details in the code snippet below)

**The issue I am having is that I need to only return a match where the initial string order of String 2 is maintained. Ex:
If:
String 1 = Red Green Blue
String 2 = Blue Red
This is not a valid match since even though when we split String 2, we find the resulting array elements are "contained" in String 1, the order of String 2 is not being respected.**

Here is a rough draft of the logic I've coded:

```
splitString = Split(String2," ")
x = -1
For y = LBound(splitString) To UBound(splitString)
     splitStringCompare = InStr(1, String1, splitString(y), vbTextCompare)
     If splitStringCompare > 0 Then
        x = x + 1
         If x = UBound(splitString) Then
            "Match"
             Else
             "No Match"
         End If
Next y
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Is this matching case sensitive?

Comment: Hi, no it does not need to be case sensitive. Thanks

Comment: `If String2 Like "*" & Replace(string1, " ", "*") & "*" Then`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expressions object to test this and verify match. For demonstration purpose, I have created a UDF as below.

```
Public Function MatchWildCard(strMatchWith As String, strMatchString As String) As Boolean
    strMatchString = Replace(Trim(strMatchString), " ", ".+")
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True '\\ Change to False if match is case sensitive
        .Pattern = strMatchString
        If .Test(strMatchWith) Then
            MatchWildCard = True
        Else
            MatchWildCard = False
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

It can then be used in Excel sheet like below snapshot `=MatchWildCard(A1,B1)`:
[image]

**Note:** I am a basic user of RegExp so there may be a better manner of handling this so you should test this on large sample to validate.

Comment: Great, at first glance this seems to cover off all of the requirements. I am not too familiar with RegExp, but this seems to accomplish the task in much cleaner fashion. I will test on a wider data set to confirm. Thank you!

Comment: If you are like me and regular expressions aren't your daily diet, I found [The RegEx Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) a very helpful tool for figuring out the right/most optimal regular expression. A word of caution, though: regular expression engines come in all sorts of "flavor" so that a certain pattern might work in engine A, but gives different results in engine B.

Comment: @HelO'Ween, I will definitely check it when time permits.